How can i achieve this in the percentage indicator or custom widget in flutter?
I working on a project where I wanted to create a stats widget which displays the calories required in a multi valued percentage indicator and I tried a lot of repos to get it done. But, eventually I failed on recreating it. Can somebody make this happen?

This is a Figma UI and I have to recreate in Flutter using dart

Have you tried percent_indicator package?

yes ,it can be stacked but not the way i want

Using:

capped_progress_indicator
pie_chart

Here's an example.
import 'package:capped_progress_indicator/capped_progress_indicator.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pie_chart/pie_chart.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: false),
      home: PieChartWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class PieChartWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const PieChartWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Data for the pie chart
    Map<String, double> dataMap = {
      "Red": 47,
      "Green": 41,
      "Blue": 16,
    };

    // List of colors
    final colorList = <Color>[
      Colors.indigo.shade300,
      Colors.red.shade300,
      Colors.green.shade300
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
           height: 80,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              PieChart(
                dataMap: dataMap,
                colorList: colorList,
                chartType: ChartType.ring,
                chartRadius: 150,
                // centerText: "241",
                centerWidget: const Text.rich(TextSpan(children: [
                  TextSpan(
                      text: "241\n",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  TextSpan(text: "kcal")
                ])),
                ringStrokeWidth: 10,
                        
                chartValuesOptions: ChartValuesOptions(
                    showChartValues: false, showChartValueBackground: false),
                chartLegendSpacing: 0.0,
                        
                legendOptions: LegendOptions(
                  showLegends: false,
                ),
                // chartValuesOptions: ChartValuesOptions(
                //   showChartValuesInPercentage: true,
                //   showChartValuesOutside: false,
                //   showChartValues: true,
                //   decimalPlaces: 0,
                // ),
                // legendOptions: LegendOptions(
                //   showLegendsInRow: false,
                //   legendPosition: LegendPosition.right,
                //   showLegends: true,
                //   legendShape: BoxShape.circle,
                //   legendTextStyle: TextStyle(
                //     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                //   ),
                // ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 30),
              PercentageWidget(
                title: "28.2g",
                value: 47,
                typeTitle: "carbs",
                color: colorList[0],
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 30),
              PercentageWidget(
                title: "10.9g",
                value: 41,
                typeTitle: "fat",
                color: colorList[1],
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 30),
              PercentageWidget(
                title: "9.8g",
                value: 16,
                typeTitle: "protein",
                color: colorList[2],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PercentageWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const PercentageWidget(
      {super.key,
      required this.title,
      required this.value,
      required this.typeTitle,
      required this.color});

  final String title;
  final double value;
  final String typeTitle;

  final Color color;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 45,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          Text(
            typeTitle,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, color: Colors.grey.shade600),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 3),
          LinearCappedProgressIndicator(
              color: color,
              backgroundColor: color.withOpacity(0.5),
              cornerRadius: 10,
              value: value / 100,
              minHeight: 6),
          SizedBox(height: 2),
          Text(
            '$value' "%",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: color,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Note:

I run this code in flutter web. So, handle your required width and height accordingly.
Explore more chart or progress type widget on pub.dev to create the exact pie chart which is shown in the UI.
This is just an example. You can remove duplicate widget code based on your data.

Output: 

Thanks bro for teaching and i want to ask something do learn to code java/dart yourself on time or any courses ,anything will help me

Learn from flutter's site, and youtube.
